# Angular 6.0.1 CLI throws "Architect" error on "ng lint --type-check" execution

Tags: angular, angular-cli, lint, angular6, angular-cli-v6

After the Angular and Angular CLI update to v6, my lint configuration is throwing the following error everytime I try to run `ng lint --type-check`:

> Architect commands with multiple targets cannot specify overrides. 'lint' would be run on the following projects: atlas-fe,atlas-fe-e2e
>
> Error: Architect commands with multiple targets cannot specify overrides. 'lint' would be run on the following projects: atlas-fe,atlas-fe-e2e
>     at LintCommand.validate (/home/nroma/workspace/atlas/proto-fe/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:75:23)
>     at /home/nroma/workspace/atlas/proto-fe/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:274:39
>     at Generator.next ()
>     at /home/nroma/workspace/atlas/proto-fe/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:7:71
>     at new Promise ()
>     at __awaiter (/home/nroma/workspace/atlas/proto-fe/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:3:12)
>     at validateAndRunCommand (/home/nroma/workspace/atlas/proto-fe/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:273:12)
>     at Object. (/home/nroma/workspace/atlas/proto-fe/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:100:26)
>     at Generator.next ()
>     at fulfilled (/home/nroma/workspace/atlas/proto-fe/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:4:58)

I'm using **node v9.9.0 (npm v6.0.1)**.

This is my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "atlas-fe",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "npm run lint-ts && npm run lint-css",
    "lint-ts": "npm run format-ts && ng lint --type-check",
    "lint-css": "npm run format-css && stylelint \"src/**/*.{scss,css}\"",
    "format": "npm run format-ts && npm run format-css",
    "format-ts": "clang-format -i --glob=\"{src,e2e}/**/*.{js,ts}\"",
    "format-css": "stylefmt -c .stylelintrc -r \"src/**/*.{scss,css}\"",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "precommit": "npm run lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "6.0.0-beta.15",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "fuse.js": "^3.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "clang-format": "^1.2.2",
    "codelyzer": "^4.1.0",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "stylefmt": "^6.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^1.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I meant Angular and Angular CLI **6.0.1**

Comment: Related: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10810, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10765. This seems more like a bug report than an SO question.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. It would seem that there is no way around it for now but to use `tsc --noEmit` instead of `ng lint --type-check`, whatever that thing is :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the CLI now defines two apps for your: your-site and your-site-e2e. Running `ng lint` implicitly runs both by adding the two project names after the command somewhere under the hood.

However, if you add the `--type-check` flag to your command the implicit result becomes `ng lint --type-check your-site your-site-e2e` which is an invalid order of arguments.

To fix it change the following line:

```
"lint-ts": "npm run format-ts && ng lint --type-check",
```

to the explicit variant:

```
"lint-ts": "npm run format-ts && ng lint atlas-fe atlas-fe-e2e --type-check",
```

There is an open issue about this on the angular-cli [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11005) but so far not much activity.

Comment: That seems to fix it! Thank you very much Stephan!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to this problem. You need to specify the target for the lint command which is both the `project` & the `project-e2e`.
So in my case I had this object in my script:

```
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build --prod ",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint --force ",
```

I just changed the lint line :

```
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "lint": "ng lint --force name-project name-project-e2e",
```